# Mapping over a JSON array of objects and processing values using JQ

Tags: json, ubuntu, jq

Just started playing around with `jq` and cannot for the life of me come to terms with how I should approach this in a cleaner way. I have some data from AWS SSM Parameter Store that I receive as JSON, that I want to process.

The data is structured in the following way

```
[
    {
        "Name": "/path/to/key_value",
        "Value": "foo"
    },
    {
        "Name": "/path/to/key_value_2",
        "Value": "bar"
    },
    ...
]
```

I want it output in the following way: `key_value=foo key_value_2=bar`. My first thought was to process it as follows: `map([.Name | split("/") | last, .Value] | join("=")) | join(" ")` but then I get the following error: `jq: error (at <stdin>:9): Cannot index array with string "Value"`. It's as if the reference to the `Value` value is lost after piping the value for the `Name` parameter.

Of course I could just solve it like this, but it's just plain ugly: `map([.Value, .Name | split("/") | last] | reverse | join("=")) | join(" ")`. How do I process the value for `Name` without losing reference to `Value`?

**Edit:** [JQ Play link](https://jqplay.org/s/i1_jN3sB4SI)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
map((.Name | split("/") | last) + "=" + .Value) | join(" ")
```

Will output:

```
"key_value=foo key_value_2=bar"
```

##### [Online demo](https://jqplay.org/s/ry_UIFyln4r)

The 'trick' is to wrap the `.Name | split("/") | last)` into `()` so that `.value` remains available

---

---

If you prefer [string interpolation](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/manual/#Stringinterpolation-%5C(foo)) (`\()`) over `(key) + .Value`, you can rewrite it as:

```
map("\(.Name | split("/") | last)=\(.Value)") | join(" ")
```

##### [Online demo](https://jqplay.org/s/Qmthe5y-wGQ)

Comment: `.Name | sub(".*/"; "")` is also an option.